# Formal alternative to phrasal verb "turn down"

Tags: formality

I wish to state on my curriculum vitae something along the following line:

```
Scholarship turned down to pursue a career in industry.
```

I find phrasal verbs (like *turn down*) rather informal. Is there a more formal way to make such a statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Declined", especially "Scholarship declined in favour of pursuing...".  MW has this:

> to refuse especially courteously: decline an invitation

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decline

You could also use "rejected", but this sounds rather negative toward the scholarship.

Comment: There is also "refused", of course, but that is also a bit negative.

Answer (score 1):

You could put something along the lines of:

> The need to begin a career in industry prevented me from accepting the scholarship.